# How to avoid not trigger ripple when scroll sectionList in react native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-native-sectionlist

I'm using sectionList with pressable items. It may like this:

```
<SectionList
  data={list}
  renderItem={(item) => {
    return <Pressable android_ripple={{ color: gray, borderless: true }} />
  }}
/>
```

The ripple give a simple way to realize user effect after press, but I find it will trigger when scroll. That's quite not pretty. Is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need to use `onPressIn` or `onPressOut`, I would recommend going with TouchableOpacity. Its animation wont be triggered by scrolling. If you need to use `Pressable`, you could start off by removing the ripple effect while scrolling:

```js
const [isScrolling, setIsScrolling] = useState(false)

return (
  <SectionList
    data={list}
    renderItem={(item) => {
      return (
        <Pressable
          android_ripple={!isScrolling &&{ color: gray, borderless: true }}
          unstable_pressDelay={200}
        />
      )
    }}
   onScrollBeginDrag={()=>{
     console.log('Scroll started')
     setIsScrolling(true)
   }}
   onScrollEndDrag={()=>{
     console.log('Scroll ended')
     setIsScrolling(false)
   }}
  />
)
```

The problem with this approach is that sometimes the Pressable `onPressIn` event fires before `isScrolling` is updated, and the ripple effect occurs anyway. I am using `unstable_pressDelay` to delay long enough for the update

Comment: Just found out that Pressable if you are using react native 0.69 and under `Pressable` have the `unstable_pressDelay` prop that will allow you to delay the animation long enough for the state to change

Comment: Actually with `unstable_pressDelay` it looks like `isScrolling` isnt needed at all

Comment: Yep, I have the idea that set ripple effect by listen scroll events at first. But I think it may cause performance problem because every item in list will update. I think delay trigger press a good way and it works well for my program. But your code seems like some wrong. The `unstable_pressDelay` prop belongs to `Pressable` not `SectionList`.  Anyway, thanks your help. Wish you have a nice day.

Comment: ohyeah ur right. Where I was testing it renderItem was in a separate file from the SectionList